# How to get gamma of image in HSI color space

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, gamma

I am required to change Gamma of a photo using HSI color space. I changed RGB to HSI color space and know that I need to change the intensity with Gamma value. But I don't know how to find gamma value of the image since HSI is just hue,saturation and intensity. Anyone know how I can find Gamma value? I hardly can find anything online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as "gamma value of the image". What you were required is to change the curve of the tone mapping, which is frequently called `gamma`, due to historical reasons.

In order to do this, use some sort of monotonically rising curve that is applied on the `I` channel, or on `R`, `G` and `B` together. The most used example is to use a power function -> `y=x^(p)`, where `p` is a parameter. (To make things more confusive, `p` is often called `gamma` as well.)

Comment: Thank but how do I decide the value of P?

Comment: @ATZ, it will depend on how the image originated and why you're trying to change the gamma. For example a camera sensor will react linearly to light but a display requires a gamma of 2.2 so p=2.2/1 (but this is normally done automatically in-camera). Old Macs used a gamma of 1.8 in the display, so to convert a normal 2.2 image to 1.8 use p=1.8/2.2.